# Implement payment with Bizum, Paypal, CreditCard in my web-app React

Tags: reactjs, paypal, frontend

I'm trying to create a web-app with React that accepts payments by Bizum (the most important), Paypal, Creditcard (due the fees I'd guess that I will only accept Bizum though), but I can't find an easy way to implement that for my react web-app.

From now I have this code

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Human Information</h1>
      {performer ? (
        <div className="human-info">
        <h2>{human.name}</h2>
        <p>{human.description}</p>
        <img src={human.imageURL} alt="Human Image" />
        {human.paymentMethods.includes('Bizum') && <BizumPayment />}
      </div>
      ) : (
        <p>Loading human information...</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
```

Then I've created the `BizumPayment`to split the functionality of each payment methods

```
import React from 'react';

function BizumPayment() {
  const handleBizumPayment = () => {
    // Implement Bizum payment process here
    console.log("Initiating Bizum payment...");
    // Add your Bizum payment integration logic here
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={handleBizumPayment}>Pay with Bizum</button>
  );
}

export default BizumPayment;
```

What are the next steps of doing this? Is there any company that accepts all of the payments? Or do I have to install three different things for each payment method?